# Terraria Boss Issue: (ref string, ref string): no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#

So, i like to make bosses, but this came along

> (ref string, ref string): no suitable method found to override

And here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace Modofmods.NPCS.Boss
{
public class BossName : ModNPC
{
    public override void SetDefaults()
    {
        npc.name = "Vesillian";
        npc.displayName = "Vesillian";
        npc.aiStyle = 22;  //5 is the flying AI
        npc.lifeMax = 180;   //boss life
        npc.damage = 20;  //boss damage
        npc.defense = 10;    //boss defense
        npc.knockBackResist = 0f;
        npc.width = 100;
        npc.height = 100;
        animationType = NPCID.DemonEye;   //this boss will behavior like the DemonEye
        Main.npcFrameCount[npc.type] = 2;    //boss frame/animation 
        npc.value = Item.buyPrice(0, 40, 75, 45);
        npc.npcSlots = 1f;
        npc.boss = true;
        npc.lavaImmune = true;
        npc.noGravity = true;
        npc.noTileCollide = true;
        npc.soundHit = 8;
        npc.soundKilled = 14;
        npc.buffImmune[24] = true;
        music = MusicID.Title;
        npc.netAlways = true;
    }


    public override void AutoloadHead(ref string headTexture, ref string bossHeadTexture)
    {
        bossHeadTexture = "Modofmods/NPCS/Boss/BossName_Head_Boss"; //the boss head texture
    }
    public override void BossLoot(ref string name, ref int potionType)
    {
        potionType = ItemID.LesserHealingPotion;   //boss drops
        Item.NewItem((int)npc.position.X, (int)npc.position.Y, npc.width, npc.height, mod.ItemType("YourSword"));
    }
    public override void ScaleExpertStats(int numPlayers, float bossLifeScale)
    {
        npc.lifeMax = (int)(npc.lifeMax * 0.579f * bossLifeScale);  //boss life scale in expertmode
        npc.damage = (int)(npc.damage * 0.6f);  //boss damage increase in expermode
    }
    public override void AI()
    {
        npc.ai[0]++;
        Player P = Main.player[npc.target];
        if (npc.target < 0 || npc.target == 255 || Main.player[npc.target].dead || !Main.player[npc.target].active)
        {
            npc.TargetClosest(true);
        }
        npc.netUpdate = true;

        npc.ai[1]++;
        if (npc.ai[1] >= 230)  // 230 is projectile fire rate
        {
            float Speed = 20f;  //projectile speed
            Vector2 vector8 = new Vector2(npc.position.X + (npc.width / 2), npc.position.Y + (npc.height / 2));
            int damage = 10;  //projectile damage
            int type = mod.ProjectileType("ProBoss");  //put your projectile
            Main.PlaySound(23, (int)npc.position.X, (int)npc.position.Y, 17);
            float rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(vector8.Y - (P.position.Y + (P.height * 0.5f)), vector8.X - (P.position.X + (P.width * 0.5f)));
            int num54 = Projectile.NewProjectile(vector8.X, vector8.Y, (float)((Math.Cos(rotation) * Speed) * -1), (float)((Math.Sin(rotation) * Speed) * -1), type, damage, 0f, 0);
            npc.ai[1] = 0;
        }
        if (npc.ai[0] % 600 == 3)  //Npc spown rate

        {
            NPC.NewNPC((int)npc.position.X, (int)npc.position.Y, mod.NPCType("NpcName"));  //NPC name
        }
        npc.ai[1] += 0;
        if (npc.life <= 70)  //when the boss has less than 70 health he will do the charge attack
            npc.ai[2]++;                //Charge Attack
        if (npc.ai[2] >= 20)
        {
            npc.velocity.X *= 0.98f;
            npc.velocity.Y *= 0.98f;
            Vector2 vector8 = new Vector2(npc.position.X + (npc.width * 0.5f), npc.position.Y + (npc.height * 0.5f));
            {
                float rotation = (float)Math.Atan2((vector8.Y) - (Main.player[npc.target].position.Y + (Main.player[npc.target].height * 0.5f)), (vector8.X) - (Main.player[npc.target].position.X + (Main.player[npc.target].width * 0.5f)));
                npc.velocity.X = (float)(Math.Cos(rotation) * 12) * -1;
                npc.velocity.Y = (float)(Math.Sin(rotation) * 12) * -1;
            }
            //Dust
            npc.ai[0] %= (float)Math.PI * 2f;
            Vector2 offset = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(npc.ai[0]), (float)Math.Sin(npc.ai[0]));
            Main.PlaySound(2, (int)npc.position.X, (int)npc.position.Y, 20);
            npc.ai[2] = -300;
            Color color = new Color();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((int)npc.position.X, (int)(npc.position.Y + ((npc.height - npc.width) / 2)), npc.width, npc.width);
            int count = 30;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                int dust = Dust.NewDust(npc.position, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height, 6, 0, 0, 100, color, 2.5f);
                Main.dust[dust].noGravity = false;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    //Boss second stage texture
    private const int Sphere = 50;
    public override bool PreDraw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Color drawColor)
    {
        if (npc.life <= 70)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(mod.GetTexture("NPCs/Boss/boss1"), npc.Center - Main.screenPosition, null, Color.White * (70f / 255f), 0f, new Vector2(Sphere, Sphere), 3f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        }
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

So, I put a little too much (I guess.) But i've been reaching out to people for weeks and still cant find any answers, so my last resort is this.
And its not easy, the same thing happens with my tiles, and even my armor.

Comment: Post the full error message please.

Comment: Step 1. Check the method signature of the method you're overriding. Step 2. Copy the method signature and change `virtual` or `abstract` to `override`. --- Alternatively, click somewhere in the class body (not inside a method) and type `override` and select the method you want to override. You'll see that its signature is different to the signature of your current override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at the mod loader's [ModNPC.cs](https://github.com/blushiemagic/tModLoader/blob/master/patches/tModLoader/Terraria.ModLoader/ModNPC.cs) and I can't see a `AutoloadHead` method at all.

Looking at the code I found that the properties `HeadTexture` and `BossHeadTexture` seem to be virtual, so instead of using `AutolaodHead` (which, if it existed, doesn't exist anymore), you should just override `BossHeadTexture`:

```
public override string BossHeadTexture => "Modofmods/NPCS/Boss/BossName_Head_Boss";
```

You can see the relevant properties [here](https://github.com/blushiemagic/tModLoader/blob/master/patches/tModLoader/Terraria.ModLoader/ModNPC.cs#L58-L70).